# Do DPI-Groups of WinPhone8 and WinRT Displays exist?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, dpi, windows-rt

Does Microsoft group WinPhone8 and WinRT device's displays into groups/categories as Apple (iOS: standard and retina) and Google (Android: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, etc.) do?

WinPhone8 DPI range from about 220 up to 440, so I doubt that's all "standard".
I've searched but found nothing…

If someone could give me a link to the docs that would be great!

Why do I need this Info:

I'm adding WinPhone8 and WinRT support to my Unity3d Editor extension xARM.

It provides a sortable list of resolutions, display diagonals, … and *DPI-Groups* per platform. Currently the DPI-Group-Column is empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 and Windows RT devices aren't grouped into DPI categories.
However both platforms have their own scaling system which is based on resolution (not DPI). So it *could* be used for grouping, but it's not a very helpful info.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx